# how to add an Expires or a Cache-Control Header programmatic in #asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

i host my web site into a shared hosting and i need to set expiration header using iis but i didn't find my hosting allow this feature so , is there any way to set it into my web configuration or into my code ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google is your friend :)

[MSDN Article: HttpResponse.AddHeader Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.addheader(VS.71).aspx)

You can also use HttpResponse.AppendHeader, which is semantically the same as HttpResponse.AddHeader.

Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in Page_Load

```
Response.Headers.Add("Expires", "ddd, dd m YYYY hh:mm:ss GMT");
```

You have to change the date for yours

Comment: is this will work with the page all for all the items related to my pages like images .

Comment: No this will only set the cache header for the HTML page.